# the mathmatical best algorithm for pi

Tags: algorithms, pi

every time i find a good method, a better one appears and makes the previous one seem ridiculous, like some time ago when i found a good linear convergence method for pi and i suddenly came across gauss-legendre method, that was muuuuuuuch better then the linear one (its quadratic)

and then i found [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borwein%27s_algorithm#Nonic_convergence) wikipedia page that got up to NONIC convergence (but not working ಠ╭╮ಠ)

then i found an Hexadecimalic convergence method for pi (i still did not tested and i only found two sites in the whole google that talked about it!!!)

now i dont have any idea if this is the best algorithm that math has to offer, if there is a even better one thats wating to be discovered or if there are infinitely good that get infinitely hard

the formal question is: is there a bound on how good pi algorithms can get? if yes, what?

Comment: You may be interested in this program, I believe it has been used to set several records http://www.numberworld.org/y-cruncher/

Comment: i am a programmer, then i always prefer to program everything myself (if its not way too hard)

Comment: The creator of that project has this github repo where he prioritizes readability https://github.com/Mysticial/Mini-Pi

Comment: Here is a good place to note that Ramanujan expressed $1/\pi$ as an infinite series which converges rapidly: https://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc/notes/pi/ramanujan.html

Comment: There is a bound in the sense that it is known that $\pi$ is not a Liouville number.

Comment: To answer your question effectively, you need to be precise about what you mean by "how good pi algorithms can get". It is very likely that no matter how good of an algorithm, there exists one even better similar to how given any approximation to $\pi$ there is always a better approximation.

Answer (score 2):

In the page given by @Matthew Pilling, the formula
$$\frac{1}{\pi}
= \frac{1}{53360 \sqrt{640320}}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n
\frac{(6n)!}{(n!)^3(3n)!} \times
\frac{13591409 + 545140134n}{640320^{3n}}\tag1$$  due to the Chudnovsky brothers is really spectacular.

Computing the ratio of successive terms, we have
$$\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|= \frac{1}{151931373056000}-\frac{1}{303862746112000
   n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$ while, for the Great Ramanujan's formula
$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{1}{96059601}-\frac{1}{192119202 n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$

Moreover, $(1)$ is alternating. So, we know in advance how many terms have to be added for $k$ exact decimal places. As a first order approximation
$$n_k\sim \left\lceil \frac{13}{849} W\left(\frac{4912}{1321}\times 10^{(2 k-27)}\right)\right\rceil$$ where $W(.)$ is Lambert function.

For $k=1000$, $n=70$.